# Flutter rxdart stream accelerometer

Tags: flutter, accelerometer, rxdart

I using [sensors_plus 1.0.2](https://pub.dev/packages/sensors_plus) accelerometer to calculate degrees. The default accelerometerEvents is too fast, I tried adding the debouceTime to slower down the emit, but it doesn't work

```
accelerometerEvents.debounceTime(Duration(milliseconds: 500)).listen((AccelerometerEventevent) {
  print(event);
});
```